# What is the name of the round metal bit at the top of a bathtub drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathtub

At the top of the drain there is this round metal drain bit what is it called?

I am looking to replace this top metal bit of my bathtub drain and need help identifying what it is called.

[image: Round metal bit of the drain that I am looking for]

Comment: That is the *strainer*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is UK terminology.

As a unit it's a *'bath waste'*, but that includes the part it's screwed to underneath and quite often the pipe & overflow linkage too - everything above the trap.

If you want only the part you can see in the photo, it's a *'jumper plate'* - but be careful, because a jumper is also a tap [faucet] washer.
I have to admit to having to look up what just this bit is called. I've never dealt with anything smaller than the entire waste, which also tends to be how you buy them; as complete sets.

If you were to visit a merchant's in person, you could get away with just calling it a *'plug hole'* & wait for them to ask you which bit of it you require & what size. Bath wastes tend to be 40mm standard, though ask for 'inch & a half' as we Brits seem to have hung onto that as a definition.

BTW, be very very careful of just unscrewing the jumper plate unless you can reach underneath to hold it up. That's not a predicament you want to be in if you have tiled the bath sides, or can't come in from the ceiling below. Your question doesn't make it clear just what access you have or quite what you intend to do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed help the jumper plate, in my new bathroom was in a bad shape / rusted corroded and dirty. I am renting and wanted to replace it with something nicer.

Answer (score 2):

I would call this the "tub drain trim piece"- (*US terminology here*)

The overall assembly is called a "Waste and Overflow". This includes the Drain and the overflow and the piping which connects the two behind the tub and combines to a single pipe which connects to your house drain piping. (*See Image*)

It can be metal or plastic and does vary depending on your tub size. The trim piece can be difficult to replace as you will not have access to the under side of the tub to hold the back side of the fitting. The above picture shows the drain trim piece which should be set into the tub with plumber's putty. Under the tub there is the brass fitting with a thick rubber washer that seals against the tub bottom. Usually a plumber can do the trim replacement from above- **very carefully**-  this is not at all a convenient place to have a leak.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the helpful comment is the tub drain trim piece the whole piece you have pictured or only the metal cover part?

Comment: The picture shows the entire "waste and overflow assembly"- a part of which is the tub drain trim piece- the piece on the bottom inside the tub which you see